# Partial object type which also allows arrays of the properties (preferably only primitives)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type which is a partial of the generic type, but also allows an array as property from the corresponding type. So basically if you have the following interface:

```
interface DataModel {
  type: string;
  count: number;
}
```

The resolved type should have the following signature

```js
{
  type?: string | string[];
  count?: number | number[];
}
```

and behave the following:

```js
{ type: 'foo'} // ok
{ type: ['foo', 'bar'] } //ok
{ type: 1 } // error
```

I came up with this utility type, but this also allows non corresponding types to the property:

```js
type KeyOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;

type FilterProps<
  T extends object,
  U extends KeyOf<T> = KeyOf<T>
> = Partial<Record<U, T[U] | T[U][]>>;
```

I've made a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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) which clarifies it a bit more

---

Preferably it would also fail on properties on the model that are not primitives, but that's not a hard requirement for me, and perhaps I can figure that one out myself.

Comment: please provide explanation why are you expect an error in your examples

Comment: @captain-yossarian I've updated it a bit more, explaining what the resolved type should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map each key to a different type:

```
interface DataModel {
  type: string;
  count: number;
}

type FilterProps<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] | T[K][]
}

let test1: FilterProps<DataModel> = { type: 'foo' }
let test2: FilterProps<DataModel> = { type: ['foo', 'bar'] }
let test3: FilterProps<DataModel> = { type: 1 } // Error
```

Comment: Oh my, I was thinking way too difficult about this. Of course! Thanks a lot for showing me the way :)

Answer (score 1):

To build upon @daylily's answer and to only allow primitives from the source object you can do the following:

```js
type FilterProps<T> =  {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends (string | number | boolean)
    ? T[K] | T[K][]
    : never
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAeAKgPigXigUQA9gAnAQwGNgUBreAeySjQBooBnEgSwDsBzDANwAoIaEhQAYpwA2wCMQAKxOpGLBOENuiy4oAbygBtGFB5RaIBkwC6AfgBcTY9agQiEbgBM2UABQdiHl4oAB8obgBXAFsAI3lQqBi6OmkIUm4ASihbJxgXMLRnQxdHbggAN3iAX2EhHjliJApoABFSYFIAWTpPCGl9ISgoMQhHAKDhIfI6CO5gUui44kmoCnVKxySUtO4VsFJiD2AHKDaO7t7pYSqRAHpbqDpqIWnuDigkGQaARkcpWXkShU8nUmhQZy6PT6OgGQxGjgA5FFSDwEUIbkJ7o9nq93p8AcQAEx-L6A5SqUFaCEXaE4WHDcCjIxIlHcBGsBH7NScUjSBHWdF3B5sAAWM2knlcxGUxBedDewA+pOIAGYSQSgRSNFT2pDLjC9IMGZBHABWQWY4ViiISqUyuUKpUEgAs6oampB2vBupp0gNRq5R0cBnhUAR7Kg01m8ygAAZWGtOBsPry2NAblUgA)